# Nest Custom GWT Data Grid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I'm trying to figure out if the following picture is possible in GWT with a custom Data Grid. I have each row that contains customer information and then a second Data Grid to the right that shows orderline information. I'm basing it loosely off the [GWT example](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid), but that only shows "friends" with the same attributes under each person, and doesn't show a nest Data Grid. So is this possible? any tips on where to start? I've done a normal Data Grid but this is a little more complex so advice or examples would be helpful. Smart GWT is not an option.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the optimal solution but you can have nested html table code in the Cell

Example

```
...
 userColumn = new Column<User, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {
      @Override
      public SafeHtml getValue(User user) {
        SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<table style=\"width:100%\">");
        for (Product product : user.getProducts()) {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<tr>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>" +product.getProductNumber()+"</td>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>" +product.getName()+"</td>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>" +product.getQuality()+"</td>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<tr>");
        }
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</table>");
        return sb.toSafeHtml();
      }
    };
```